# Safety check: How to restrict the # of rows affected in an Oracle Update/Delete query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a miniature ORM-like component in my application that handles query generation for basic update/delete operations, but I need to build in some safety at the query level since primary keys are determined automatically (a second level of anal, if you will).

By design, whenever I update or delete a row, it should affect 1 row only.

So, given the following query:

`UPDATE Cars SET Color = 'Red' WHERE CarID = 5`

How can I tell Oracle: **"... this query should affect 1 row. If it affects any more than 1 row, throw a big hairy error and don't do anything."**?

That way, suppose someday there is a bug and this query is executed:

`UPDATE Cars SET Color = 'Red'`

... it will just blow up instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might not want the ROLLBACK in there but if there's a problem you usually want to rollback the update:

```
DECLARE
   update_exception EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
   UPDATE Cars 
      SET Color = 'Red' 
    WHERE CarID = 5;
   --
   IF SQL%ROWCOUNT > 1
   THEN
      RAISE update_exception;
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN update_exception
   THEN
      ROLLBACK;
      -- Do your error handling...
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [SQL%ROWCOUNT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/static.htm#CJACIHFD) to determine the number of affected records before committing the transaction and throw an exception in case > 1.

Comment: @routeNpingme, follow the link :)